# Can I have multiple run methods in a class?

Tags: java

If so, how? I need to have 2 run methods in each object I will instantiate.

I meant a run method for threading.

What i need is more like a race of two cars. each car should have a name and a run() method in a class which extends Thread. I will have to call on the two cars in my main to see which will win. The first or the second. I need help in starting my program

Comment: are you talking about the run method for threading? If that's what you mean, then no. I mean you could have overloaded run methods, but the interface only has one method. So you only implement that run method.

Comment: What you mean with `run method`? A method with you can run from command-line?

Comment: yes @pqsk I meant a run method for threading. I forgot to indicate it. If that is so, thank you.

Comment: The `run` method is executed when the thread starts. If there are two run methods -- say `run1` and `run2` which one would you wanted to be executed?

Comment: can't i execute both? what i need is more like a race of two cars. each car should have a name and a run() method in a class which extends Thread. I will have to call on the two cars in my main to see which will win. The first or the second. I need help in starting my program.

Comment: @StellaKim You could just have each car run on a separate thread. If you have any code already post it, or are you just not understanding threading?

Answer (score 6):

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){public void run(){...}})
Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){public void run(){....}})
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

By using inner class you can achieve multiple run methods in a single class.

Answer (score 5):

A class can't contain two methods with the same *signature*. The signature of a method is its name followed by its arguments.

You may thus have `run(int)` and `run(String)` and `run()` in the same class. This is called *method overloading*. You can't have two `run()` methods, because you (and the compiler) could not know which one to execute when calling `obj.run()`.

Answer (score 3):

What for?  I assume you're talking about implementing the runnable interface, so you want two methods with the signature: `public void run();`?

Having two methods with the same signature makes no sense; how would you distinguish between them when calling the method from elsewhere in your code?

If you want two different things to happen based on a certain condition when `run()` is invoked, then you need to add a conditional statement at the start of the method:

```
public void run() {

    if (some_condition) {

        // code for the first scenario

    } else {

        // code for the second

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
 public class Car extends Thread
 {
      public String name;

      public Car(String name)
      {
           this.name = name;
      }
      public void run()
      {
           //your code
      }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
      Thread car1 = new Car("car1's name");
      Thread car2 = new Car("car2's name");
      car1.start();
      car2.start();

 }
```

You can add your logic into Car.run(), but basically that's how I would do that. In your logic determine when it starts and ends. When both threads finish, you can see which one is the winner. You could also add a while loop and have a field in Car that is a boolean type to determine if it's finished or not.

Answer (score 1):

As you asked, you want to know if it's possible to have more than one `run()` method in a class that implements the [Runnable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface, or extends the [Thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) class.

You can just think about the definition of a thread. A thread is a single instructions block, contained inside a process, that's why a thread is called as a **lightweight process**. Generally, a thread executes only a specific task.

A new thread is created when the main process of a program needs to do multiple operations in background, such as autosaving or grammar check, if the main program is a word processor, for example. This is the concept of [multithreading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computer_science%29#Multithreading).

Now, if you read the `Runnable` or `Thread` API, you can see that the class that extends `Thread` class or implements the `Runnable` class, overrides (in case you are extending `Thread` class) the run() method or implements the abstract method `run()` (in case you are implementing the `Runnable` class).

As other users said, you can use the overloading technique. You can implement another `run()` method in the class, with a different signature, because it's not a legal practice to have multiple methods with the same signature (it generates confusion for the compiler when you have to invoking one of them) and because it's non sense.

But, remember, at the moment of the starting of the thread, using, for example `Thread.start()`, then the method will invoke always the `run()` method you defined previously, with the empty signature. It's possible only to invoke another `run` method, with a different signature as `run(String s)`, in the main `run()` method of thread.

For example:

```
public class Thread implements Runnable{

   public void run(){
         //instructions
         Object o = new Object();
         run(o);
    }

   public void run(Object o){
       //other instructions
    }
} 


public class OtherClass{
    Thread t = new Thread();
    t.start(); //this will invoke the main run() method!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create two classes and call start method(basic idia) look at the example!
//class Second

```
public class Second extends Thread {
public void run() {
for (int c = 100; c > 0; c--) {
    System.out.println(c);
  }
 }
}
```

//class Main

```
public class Main extends Thread {
public void run() {
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
 }
```

}

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
Main thread_1 = new Main();
Second thread_2 = new Second();

// Let's fix concurrency problem
// method 1:

thread_1.start();
thread_1.join();
thread_2.start();
thread_2.join();

//method 2:
//or you can use  is alive
/* thread_1.start();
while (thread_1.isAlive()){
    System.out.print("");
}thread_2.start();*/


}
```

}