# How to run a class' method using thread

Tags: java, multithreading, class, methods

If I do the following, I will be able to create an object as a thread and run it.

```
class ThreadTest
{
   public static voic main(String[] args)
   {
      HelloThread hello = new HelloThread();
      Thread t = new Thread(hello);
      t.start();       
   }
}

class HelloThread extends Thread
{
   public void run()
   {
      System.out.println(" Hello ");
   }
}
```

Now, if my `HelloThread` class has a another method call `runThisPlease()`, how are we supposed to run it with a thread?

**Example:**

```
class HelloThread extends Thread
{
   public void run()
   {
      System.out.println(" Hello ");
   }

   public void runThisPlease(String input)
   {
      System.out.println (" Using thread on another class method: " + input );
   }
}
```

**Que:** When I try `Thread t = new Thread(hello.runThisPlease());`, it doesn't work. So how can we call the method `runThisPlease()` using a thread?

**Edit:** Argument needed in method for `runThisPlease()`;

Comment: call `runthisPlease` from `run`.

Comment: I understand that you want to have multple run methods in your Thread, look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569459/can-i-have-multiple-run-methods-in-a-class

Answer (score 4):

In java 8 you can use

```
Thread t = new Thread(hello::runThisPlease);
```

`hello::runThisPlease` will be converted to a `Runnable` with a run method that calls `hello.runThisPlease();`.

---

If your want to call a method, that needs parameters, e.g. `System.out.println`, you can of course use a normal lambda expression too:

```
final String parameter = "hello world";
Thread t = new Thread(() -> System.out.println(parameter));
```

---

If you use a java version < 8, you can of course replace the method reference / lambda expression with anonymus inner classes that extend `Runnable` (which is what a java8 compiler does, AFAIK), see other answers.

However you can also use a anonymus inner class that extends `Thread`:

```
final HelloThread hello = //...
Thread t = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        hello.runThisPlease();
    }
};
```

Comment: sh*t I'm getting old. Seems a good idea to have a look at the new stuff of java8

Comment: I didn't expect an answer using Java 8. I should have stated the limitations in my tags. Is it possible to do it with Java 7?

Comment: @user3437460: the other answers already mentioned that, but i also added a solution for java <8.

Answer (score 0):

Simply calling the `runThisPlease()` from within the `run()` method will make it part of a new thread.

Try this:

```
class HelloThread extends Thread
{
   public void run()
   {
      System.out.println(" Hello .. Invoking runThisPlease()");
      runThisPlease();
   }

   public void runThisPlease()
   {
      System.out.println (" Using thread on another class method ");
   }
}
```

Comment: What if `runThisPlease()` requires an argument in the method signature?

Comment: @user3437460 pass that argument to `HelloThread` constructor.

Comment: Hi, do you mind writing an example how you do it. I tried several ways, but it didn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to only call this method inside `run()` method.

```
public void run(){
  System.out.println(" Hello ");
  runThisPlease();
}
```

If you want to pass some argument then you can use below code

```
String str = "Welcome"; 

Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    System.out.println(str); 
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Things are maybe more clear if you use the Runnable interface:

```
public class HelloThread implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
       // executed when the thread is started
       runThisPlease();
    }

    public void runThisPlease() {...}
}
```

To launch this call:

```
Thread t=new Thread(new HelloThread());
t.start();
```

The Thread class can not see your extra method because it is not part of the Runnable interface.
As a convenience Thread implements Runnable but I don't think it helps in clarity :(

Comment: "As a convenience..."  It's more important that that!  The Thread class never should have implemented Runnable.  Just look at the continuing stream of questions here by people who are confused by the difference between Thread.start() and Thread.run().  The Runnable object, r, when you call `new Thread(r)` is a _delegate_.  Any time you start to write `class Foo extends Bar`, you should stop yourself and ask, "Shouldn't Foo _have_ a Bar instead of _being_ a Bar."  The answer is almost always Yes.  Using delegation instead of sub-classing usually leads to better designed programs.