# Write Multiple Threads in JAVA

Tags: java

Can we create multiple threads with multiple run methods in a class - 1 run method per 1 thread in JAVA ? 
I got a response on "[Can I have multiple run methods in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569459/can-i-have-multiple-run-methods-in-a-class)" but unable to compile the code in this way....

Comment: Yes, you can *start* multiple threads, *each* with a single run method. Why didn't you try it out instead of asking? And if you have a code that does not compile, it would be better if you specifically ask for that error (of course, *after* searching on your own why the error occurs).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what you need to do is the following...

Create your classes that you want to run in a thread make sure they implement runnable.

Then in the class that you want to create the threads from you just create a new thread (as many as you want) and pass in a new instance of the runnable class to each thread when you construct it.

Remember to call start on your thread after construction